# End of Redaction of the Mishnah and the Gemara

Tags: talmud-gemara, mishna, talmud-bavli, talmud-yerushalmi

The Talmud has three layers, the Mishnah, the Gemara and the comments (mainly Rashi for Bavli and others for Yerushalmi, who are well known).

What is the estimate timeline for the end of redaction

- of the Mishnah
- of the Gemara of the Yerushalmi
- of the Gemara of the Bavli

Is it known who (singular or plural) made the the final redaction of the Mishnah and the two Gemara? And when were they finished in the presently related from?

Comment: The Mishnah was concluded in 190 CE: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2714790/jewish/The-History-of-the-Mishnah.htm

Comment: This is an interesting question and depending upon who responds you will likely get many different answers. To understand this, you may find this linked article about the passing of Avraham Katsh of interest. https://www.nytimes.com/1998/07/26/nyregion/abraham-i-katsh-92-scholar-and-researcher-of-judaica.html

Comment: @YaakovDeane Unfortunately, the link is not accessible to all public. I don't mind to get the full scope of possible answers. In fact, I am here exactly because of this. You Jews have the best knowledge on the related Word of God of the ancient prophets and you guard it, and the Talmud is the latest source. We Muslim always ask: "Who said that?" I know that there will not be many Muslim scholars following the Talmud but all those who consider to do so will ask exactly this question.

Comment: Why are commentaries considered layers?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmud - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerusalem_Talmud